# Mojo Codehaus Properties Plugin Alternatives

Tags: java, maven, properties

I am currently trying to work with Codehaus Mojo Properties. I only found out about it this morning.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</plugin>
```

So I cant say that I am an expert on it. But when trying to build a war file I keep getting:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Circular property definition:
```

My plugin configuration is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>read-pal-properties</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>                        
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\system.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

A property that fails is:

```
webserver.websphere=WebSphere:cell=${webserver.cell},node=${webserver.node},server=${webserver.server}
```

I googled a bit about it, and saw that this is a known bug. So just wanted to see if there are other plugins that do that same job.

https://github.com/mojohaus/properties-maven-plugin/issues/27

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you have in your `pom.xml`? Are you sure that the scenario described in the above mentioned issue is exactly like your situation?

Comment: I am pretty certain it is. I updated the pom plugin part. And an example of the failure property.

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't found the answer yet after >2years, use the 1.0-alpha-2 version

Comment: hi there - could you please explain why this fixes the issue in your answer? :) cheers

Comment: Hey, I wish I could :) I found the hint somewhere a long time ago, gave it a try, and worked for me.